# Download only checked items through checkbox attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I am completely new to web development. So sorry for this lame question.

```
@foreach(){
<tr>
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="nameOfCheckBox" /> </td>
   <td> Name </td>
   <td> ID </td> 
   <td> DATA </td>
</tr>
}
```

now as many data are in database that many  will be in my view in user side. So now if my user only wants to download two or three or multiple files how to proceed in this case.
Since I am new to web I would really appreciate your answers divided into frontend and backend separately. Like what to do in frontend part and what to do in backend part.
Using C#(.net) as backend language.

Comment: Which technologies are you using in your project ? Is it blazor / razor, a backend web-api with a frontend in another techno like react, angular, vue, etc... ?

Comment: @Clement I am using razor and for frontend I mean the view I am using cshtml, css and js nothing else. Because I don't know anything else. Jquery also but that to only use $ instead of document.element.....